# End point details to consume amazon textract service

Tags: aws-sdk

I'm trying to consume amazon textract service using a rest client (Post man).

Endpoint I'm using is :

> https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Operation is POST.

Input json follows the schema :

> {   "Document":{
>            "Bytes" : "base64encoded string is here" },  "FeatureTypes":"[TABLES]" }

I keep getting this error:

> {
>       "Output": {
>           "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
>       },
>       "Version": "1.0" }

What am I missing here ?
Security headers should be good or else I would have got missing token/auth error.